# How do I hook native windows APIs from managed c# code?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, pinvoke, nt-native-api

I want to use the following native APIs:

```
NtOpenProcess 
NtOpenThread 
NtReadVirtualMemory 
NtWriteVirtualMemory 
PsCreateSystemThread 
KiAttachProcess
```

Is it possible to hook these APIs from managed C# code? If so, can someone provide an example of how this would be done?

Comment: Everything is possible. Go get some good book on windows system programming.

Comment: did you already try hooking some other APIs? if Yes, once you try to hook these ones above what does it happen?

Comment: SO's popularity means people don't even bother with the most basic research any more. Makes me long for the CodeProject days.

Comment: i think it's a valid question, just very poorly articulated. The crux of the question is useful though. Furthermore, I'd say just because the answer to this question is available out in the web, via research, doesn't mean it shouldn't be in SO. Indeed, I'd rather find the answer here than in some forum somewhere.

Comment: I see someone has edited your question to be about *calling* APIs. That's very different from *hooking* calls to those APIs. Which do you want?

Comment: Hey Cody, that's my bad, I changed it to calling. I may well be wrong, perhaps it is Hooking that Harun is looking for. Harun, could you edit your question if I've incorrectly edited it?

Comment: actually I want to hook when this apis called some programs .. and send some id to a server.. its about anti-hack for a game.. Because some people want to hack the game with cheating programs.. I want to determine who use these type programs.. then its not about calling api. its catching api which program called it.. maybe its clear ?

Comment: Then, definitively, no. This cannot be done from managed code, such as C#.

Comment: @HarunAbi, see my answer for updated guide about what you want to achieve (in C#).

Answer (score 0):

You can declare NtOpenProcess with original arguments and then DllImport("kernel32.dll") just before its declaration (you can use this method just about any dll/procedure combination).

Just like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
internal static extern int NtOpenProcess(IntPtr32 arguments...);
```

Here's an [explanation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx#pinvoke_callingdllexport).

**Update**: Actually what you want to do is doable from C#, but with the help of C++. If you want to intercept API calls from other programs, an easier way is to write the API intercepting code in C++ (using native windows functionality) and then `DllImport`-ing your C++ DLL into your C# application, doing only function calls from C# code.

Comment: thank you for your answer.. I dont want to use some api. as you said in your update, I want to intercept api.. I have to use C++ for api intercepting? If no, how do i api intercepting with c#?

Comment: He wants to *hook* calls to these functions—that is, receive a *notification* whenever *another application* calls them. This is not possible from managed code like C#, and you can't do it by simply P/Invoking a function. (I would have downvoted, but someone altered the question to say something else while it was closed. Now it's been re-opened, so I fixed it back.)

Comment: Actually, my answer includes a guide how to intercept API calls of other programs. It should be done in a C++ library which should be DllImport-ed in C# code. He will P/Invoke his own C++ code which does it for him. Maybe I didn't explain sufficiently, maybe you didn't read it fully.

Comment: But as for C++ code, intercepting api calls may cause system destabilisation. Maybe the question was edited, but OP said in comments he wanted to catch which program used these APIs, so we're on a right track.